# Scraping tweet count with rvest

Tags: r, twitter, web-scraping, rvest

I've been using the following code to scrape account's tweet count in R (faster than using API):

```
library("rvest")
scrape = read_html("https://twitter.com/whitehouse/")
scrape.count = scrape %>% 
html_nodes(".js-nav .ProfileNav-value") %>%
html_text() %>%
as.character()
scrape.count = as.numeric(paste(substr(scrape.count,1,1),substr(scrape.count,3,5),sep=""))
```

It worked perfectly till two days ago. Now it returns an empty value and I have no idea why. I used the SelectorGadget to identify the right selector and it hasn't changed. I also read that rvest may struggle with dynamic websites but until two days ago it had no issues. Any suggestions?

Comment: what does scape %>% html_text() look like?

Comment: [Twitter's TOS](https://twitter.com/en/tos) - "...scraping the Services without the prior consent of Twitter is expressly prohibited". They provide an API, probably best to use it.

Comment: @bmrn character (empty)

Comment: @SymbolixAU Thanks, wasn't aware of it. Inconvenient that scraping was a lot faster.

Comment: see [rtweet](http://rtweet.info/) and [the recipe book about it](https://rud.is/books/21-recipes/) by @hrbrmstr